# Determine Size of Entire Website

Tags: web, size

There are methods to determine the size of a webpage, but how about an entire website? Without having to download it.

EDIT: I only want pages included in the size tally that include the domain name.

Comment: For static websites you could use the Python library `Scrapy`. You would configure your scraper to store the size of Response.body.

Answer (score 1):

You have define what constitutes the website and what constitutes links and resources which aren't part of the website.  The website is essentially a graph data structure.  Do a DFS/BFS through all the links marking them visited to ensure you don't loop, catching and defining duplicates based on similar query strings, and not following links that you have defined as "not part of the website".

After all that, since you don't want to download the website, hopefully it supports the HTTP HEAD method and generates accurate Content-Length headers.  Request each of these and sum them up.

Easy, right?

OTOH, if it's your site, and you have ftp access or similar, and you define the website just to be all the files in the website's root directory, then just get the recursive directory size and you're done.  Yay!

Comment: It's not for any of my websites. I only want pages included in the size tally of the website that have the domain name included in the url. What command can I use?

Comment: There is no command.  I explained the theory.  Modern websites generate most of the pages dynamically.  You have to decide which pages are different enough to be unique counts and similar enough to be duplicates and sum up all their content headers.  If the site is TRULY only static content, no database calls, php/javascript generation based on uri parameters, you can just spider through the headers with a simple DFS.  What you are asking is not a simple command type thing.